# req.body undefined

Tags: nodejs, undefined

hola cada que imprimo  en consola me da este error podrian ayudarme ya intente algunas cosas busque un pocode documentacion pero aun no se que esta causando el error si alguien puede ayidarme se  lo agradeceria mucho
he agregado mi codigo app.js donde agrege los midleware
y el controlador de mis rutas

```js
import User from "../models/User";

export const renderSignin = async (req, res) => {
  res.render("signin");
};
export const createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = User(req.body); 
    await newUser.save();
    console.log(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }

// midelware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(indexRoutes); //* Traemos las rutas del archivo index
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
```

```html
<!-- y asi es como mando los datos desde el cliente -->
<div class="card card-body  p-4 rounded-0 bg-dark text-white">
  <h1>Create Acount</h1>
  <form action="/create/user" method="POST"><!--  Creamos la ruta del formulario-->
    <div>
      <label for="createname">Add your name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="name"
        id="createname"
        class="form-control rounded-0 bg-dark text-white"
      />

    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="createemail">Add your email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="createemail"
        placeholder="email"
        id="createemail"
        class="form-control rounded-0 bg-dark text-white"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
 <label for="createpassword">Add your pasword</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="createpassword" class="form-control rounded-0 bg-dark text-white">
    </div>
   <div>
       <label for="creatematricula"></label>Add your matricula</label>
       <input type="text" name="matricula" placeholder="matricula" id="creatematricula" class="form-control rounded-0 bg-dark text-white">
   </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Create</button>
  </form>
```

Este es el resultado que me manda despues de hacer la peticion a la ruta post y si simplementr lo intento imprimir en consola, ya sin guardarlo me arroja "req. body undefined"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías pasar código del server o index js? O sea del main del proyecto... Estás usando express?, Como estás enviando los datos al back, por post y formulario, o por llamada con Ajax, Axios, fetch o similar?.. Si usas express hay pocas razones por las que puede venirte el req.body vacío, podrías no tener name en los input del formulario, o pondria faltarte faltarte algún Middleware, ejemplo json o urlencoded..

Comment: hola si estoy usando expres  y formularios, accediendo mediante el metodo post  este esl el midleware:**//TODO: midelware
app.use(indexRoutes); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false })); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))); 
app.use(morgan("dev"));**

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir a tu pregunta cómo envías los datos desde el cliente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El Middleware del urlencoded debe estar seteado anted que las rutas.

Por otro lado si estas usando express deberías usar:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Y luego las rutas

```
app.use(indexRoutes);
```

Comment: si ahora me arroja el objeto, muchisimas gracias te agradezco te ayas molestado en ayudarme 

Comment: Me alegro mucho, si te animás a marcar la pregunta como solución dandole al "visto" al costado de la respuesta sería genial, así la pregunta se da por cerrada, no queda abierta para siempre, ayuda a mejorar la reputación y ayuda a otros a saber que funciona para poder aprovecharla si les sucede. Que tengas una excelente jornada, siempre es bueno poder dar una mano!